# Can't find documents by criteria containing string objectId value

Tags: mongodb, objectid

I have a collection list such:

```
{username: 'somename',
friendId: '57d725d6b8b144044602bf74' <-- This a reference objectId to another doc
}
```

When I query docs in my collection with criteria {friendId : '57d725d6b8b144044602bf74'} I get no results back . 
Any other field query works fine.

I tried to convert the value to `ObjectId('57d725d6b8b144044602bf74')` even though the value is just a string, still no go.

Why am I failing to search for by that type of string ?

Comment: When language are you using? my guess is that it is working with your favorite editor / mongoshell find ?

Comment: i'm using javascript. Attempted to query 1) from a cli , 2) from node plain javascript and 3) using mongoose schemas and models

Comment: Could you supply the mongoose schema ? And the part of your code with the query ?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to achieve 'self-join' in mongoDB and you seems to rely on the _id field generated by mongodb.

i would suggest you to supply custom _ID fields to the document.

eg:

```
{_id:"alex", name:"alex", friendID:""}
{_id"john", name"john", friendID:"alex"}
```

and then you can execute your queries with ease on friendID field. Give it a shot and see if this make sense for your requirement.

Comment: I could try that , but I'm confused why a string which has a value similar to an ObjectId isn't producing results. Technically it is just a plain string, and it shouldn't matter what value is in that field. I also noticed that in a mongo cli I can find my records if I make the query a regex ex: {friendId: /57d725d6b8b144044602bf74/} , but this approach still fails in code (nodejs + mongoose)